# How SSIS choose data flow tasks to be executed parallel?

Tags: ssis, parallel-execution

I have a SSIS package which has many (more than 50) dataflow tasks. When I'm executing the package I notice that maximally 6 data flow tasks executed parallelly. What I want to know is How the SSIS choose which task to be executed first? note that data flow tasks are not connected. If anyone knows any documentation regarding this, please share.

Answer (score 4):

There's no official/supported flag anywhere that enforces the order.
You can define precedence constrains to force order, but then you will loose some flexibility of parallelism.
You can increase the number of concurrent tasks (6 - default is number of cores plus 2) by setting MaxConcurrentExecutables.

You can refer to the following link for more information:

- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/parallel-execution-in-ssis-with-maxconcurrentexecutables

Comment: you are correct. but can we say that SSIS randomly chooses which task to execute first?